# Equality in Young's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, young-inequality

Let's take a look at Young's inequality: If $u,v\geqslant 0$ and $p,q$ - positive real numbers such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ then $$\dfrac{u^p}{p}+\dfrac{v^q}{q}\geqslant uv.$$
It's easy to check that if $u^p=v^q$ then we get equality.

But how to prove that if $\dfrac{u^p}{p}+\dfrac{v^q}{q}=uv$ then $u^p=v^q$?

Can anyone show to do this?

Comment: You use that $\log$ is _strictly concave_, so $\log (\mu x + (1-\mu)y) = \mu \log x + (1-\mu)\log y$ for some $\mu \in (0,1)$ only if $x = y$.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Very interesting your observation, but how can I use that fact to show what is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove it by contradiction. Suppose that $u^p>v^q$.

Let $f(x)=x^{p-1}$. Then $u^p>v^q\Leftrightarrow u^p>v^{p(q-1)}\Leftrightarrow u^{\frac{1}{q-1}}>v \Leftrightarrow u^{p-1}>v \Leftrightarrow f(u)>v$.
Let's take a look at rectangle with sides equals to $u$ and $v$. Then using usual geometric proof of Young's inequality we see that $$\dfrac{u^p}{p}+\dfrac{v^q}{q}>uv.$$
Analogous reasoning for $u^p<v^q$.

Comment: Amazing proof! Thank you!

Comment: @RaheemNajib, You are always welcome.